# How to simplify this eqauation into the form: $(a\times10^b)\times e^{cx}$?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, wolfram-alpha

I appologize, but I used a picture here because it shows directly what Wolfram outputted, and I am not very good at formatting here.

I know that $e^{cx}$ = $(e^c)^x$, but I don't know how to use it to get what Wolfram gave me.  The min() function can just be re-added later.

[Wolfram input/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCp1t.png)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all the two zeros can be cancelled. To get the leading factor you calculate

$(1.065996971366418)^{-20}\cdot 2\cdot 3.14\approx 1.7492$

Then you have to transform $1.065996971366418^{x/5}$

You take the 5-th root to get rid of the $5$ in the exponent.

$\left(\sqrt[5]{1.065996971366418}\right)^x=1.0128641371007236^x$

Now you use $a^x=e^{\ln(a)\cdot x}=\left(e^{\ln(a)}\right)^x$

$\left(e^{ln(1.0128641371007236)}\right)^x=e^{0.01278209623986817\cdot x}$